# spec cpu2006 403.gcc fail on armv7

Tags: arm, benchmarking, specifications

I'm trying to launch spec cpu2006 on my armv7 cpu but I have an error with 403.gcc test:

> 403.gcc: copy 0 non-zero return code (exit code=1, signal=0)
>
> **************************************** Contents of cccp.err
>   **************************************** gcc_base.raspberrypi-64-gcc: internal error: 8 It is possible that you may be trying to use SPEC's
>   version of gcc  without first defining the appropriate flags.  Please
>   check the flags  that are in the config files from recently-published
>   results on your  platform, and check that you are using an up-to-date
>   compiler.  If you still need help, please contact SPEC, reporting your
>   hw/os  platform, your compiler version, and your compilation flags.
>   Contact SPEC at http://www.spec.org/>
>
> ---

My build options are:

```
-DSPEC_CPU -DNDEBUG -I. -O0 -static -w -DSPEC_CPU_LP64 -DSPEC_CPU_LINUX
```

I build it with gcc-6.3. This seems to be an portability issue but I don't know what option should be added.

Comment: off-topic: why are you making a debug build (`-O0`)?  Also, did you try looking at the source file that produced that error to see what it was checking for?

Comment: @PeterCordes The -O0 is to be sure that this is not optimization error. Usually such errors occurs with portability issues. I hope to avoid source analysis but seems I'll have to.

Answer (score 0):

This may caused not by the options you setted. You need check the 403.gcc test set output result, in pathToSpec/spec_2006/spec2006_ARM64X86_mo/403.gcc/, those .s file is the output of gcc test. Just jump to the last line of .s file, if your test is right, there should be GCC version info. Spec2006 will check this line, if not exist, will warning you the GCC version not right.